# Facebook friend requests received. Can I identify the dates I have received them?

Tags: facebook

Can I identify the dates I have received a friend request if I have not accepted it?

Answer (score 1):

**No, this is not possible.**

*If you are using Facebook application on smartphone and your smartphone stores history of notifications, you might get the date of friend request received via **Notification Log**.*

Answer (score 1):

From a computer you can. Under your profile, hit the ... button then click activity log, then click filter. Scroll down and select received friends request and select the year you are looking for. If you want just the received  friends request save the changes and your done, if you want more options, select them and save the changes then your done.